# Polari doesn't join any chatroom. 'Join' button stays greyed-out (disabled)

Tags: irc

I'm trying to use polari IRC client on Ubuntu Focal (20.04) without success. The 'Join' button stays greyed-out (disabled) no matter which server or chatroom I choose.

Following are some info:

```
svinoba@focal:~$ uname -r
5.0.0-37-generic

svinoba@focal:~$ cat /etc/lsb-release
DISTRIB_ID=Ubuntu
DISTRIB_RELEASE=20.04
DISTRIB_CODENAME=focal
DISTRIB_DESCRIPTION="Ubuntu Focal Fossa (development branch)"

svinoba@focal:~$ dpkg -l polari
Desired=Unknown/Install/Remove/Purge/Hold
| Status=Not/Inst/Conf-files/Unpacked/halF-conf/Half-inst/trig-aWait/Trig-pend
|/ Err?=(none)/Reinst-required (Status,Err: uppercase=bad)
||/ Name           Version      Architecture Description
+++-==============-============-============-=================================
ii  polari         3.34.0-1     amd64        Internet Relay Chat (IRC) client
```

If I start polari from terminal, I see following error.

```
svinoba@focal:~$ polari

(polari:21203): Gjs-WARNING **: 16:31:29.656: JS ERROR: TelepathyGLib.Error: 
_onRowActivated/<@resource:///org/gnome/Polari/js/connections.js:216:27
main@resource:///org/gnome/Polari/js/main.js:63:12
run@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/package.js:222:12
start@resource:///org/gnome/gjs/modules/package.js:206:5
@<main>:1:1
```

If I search, telepathy-glib, I see two packages installed.

```
gir1.2-telepathyglib-0.12/focal,now 0.24.1-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  GLib Telepathy connection manager library (GObject-Introspection)

libtelepathy-glib0/focal,now 0.24.1-2 amd64 [installed,automatic]
  Telepathy framework - GLib library
```

Other search results for telepathy-glib results in *-dev* packages which I think are not needed(?).

I can use it on Ubuntu 18.04, Debian Sid and Arch.

From launchpad, it seems the version of polari on eoan and focal are same. Has anybody used polari on eoan (or on focal) with success?

Thanks in advance for any assistance to fix the issue.

Comment: Should work updating `telepathy-mission-control-5` to 1:5.16.5-1ubuntu1 version.

Comment: Thank you. After upgrading telepathy-mission-control, I can now login using Polari.